# Java JDBC Connection Integrity Constraint Violation

Tags: java, sql, mysql, jdbc

I created a switch case and created different classes to create Employee.
when I create an employee an entry is added in the table but i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '4' for key 'employee.PRIMARY'
    at com.siddhi.empapp.EmployeeDaoImpl.createEmployee(EmployeeDaoImpl.java:26)
    at com.siddhi.empapp.Main.main(Main.java:36)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '4' for key 'employee.PRIMARY'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:994)
    at com.siddhi.empapp.EmployeeDaoImpl.createEmployee(EmployeeDaoImpl.java:22)
    ... 1 more
```

This is the main class switch case :

```
case 1:
                    Employee emp=new Employee();
                    System.out.print("Enter ID: ");
                     id=sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
                     name=sc.next();
                    System.out.print("Enter Salary: ");
                    double salary=sc.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
                    int age=sc.nextInt();
                    emp.setId(id);
                    emp.setName(name);
                    emp.setSalary(salary);
                    emp.setAge(age);
                    dao.createEmployee(emp);
                    break;
```

This is the implementation:

```
@Override
    public void createEmployee(Employee emp) {
        con=DBConnection.createDBConnetion();
        String query="insert into employee values(?,?,?,?)";
        try {
            PreparedStatement pstm=con.prepareStatement(query);
            pstm.setInt(1,emp.getId());
            pstm.setString(2,emp.getName());
            pstm.setDouble(3,emp.getSalary());
            pstm.setInt(4,emp.getAge());
            pstm.executeUpdate();

            int cnt = pstm . executeUpdate();
            if(cnt!=0)
                System.out.println("Employee Inserted Successfully");
        }catch (SQLException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: `Duplicate entry '4' for key 'employee` does that really not give you a big clue

Comment: Try entering a number other than 4

Answer (score 0):

Try querying the database, check against the database if there is a value 4 already in the column which is set as Primary Key in your db table. If yes, you need to use a different value as suggested in comments.
I would suggest altering the table to use [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) for your ID Column.